# Error with Humanizer.Js

Tags: javascript, humanize, humanizer

I recently tried [Humanizer.Js](https://github.com/SamuelEnglard/Humanizer.Js). I added a nuget reference of the same from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HumanizerJs.Nuget), and added it in my page as `<script src="~/Scripts/humanizer/humanizer.js"></script>`. 
However in my page load I am getting an error: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" at humanizer.js:409. The stack trace looks like below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    __extends @ humanizer.js:409
    (anonymous function) @ humanizer.js:416
    Humanizer.Configuration.Humanizer.Configuration @ humanizer.js:422
    Humanizer @ humanizer.js:424
    (anonymous function) @ humanizer.js:426
```

I have also created a plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YqteuwXbCYn5xKtxLeUj?p=preview) to replicate the error. Also note that `.humanize()` also doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just released version 1.5 on NuGet, should fix your error

Comment: Hi shmuelie, thank you for your reply. You new package indeed solved my problem. I downloaded your package manually by visiting your package page on Nuget, as I couldn't download the package using Nuget from VS 2015. It says: "Could not install package 'HumanizerJs.Nuget 1.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework....". I am trying to use it in ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: I'll look into fixing that. Thanks for the heads up